# css external not working properly

Tags: css

please help. My `CSS` is not working. I tried changing the name - not working, I changed folder - and the test worked, then I tried to change style again and nothing, the style I put the first time is there even if I delete it. When I look it at developers tool in chrome it shows the style I deleted. I'm stuck. My original code is not necessary, I made just the test.php and login.css and this simple code is not working.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


 body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style/login.css">
</head>

<body>
<p> Some text </p>
</body>
</html>
```

so the first time I put `background-color: blue,` and it worked, but now I change it and it stays blue, and nothing else I do, doesn't work.

I'm working in WordPress, but from theme page, I have the link to my other page that has nothing to do with it, everything is working great, except `CSS`. could it be the conflict with WordPress?

Comment: The problem is with the navigator's cached files!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the cache. Your code works fine. In chrome

1. Open `DevTools` (Ctrl+Shift+I)
2. Open `Settings` (F1)
3. Check `Disable cache` (while DevTools is open)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! When I grow up I want to be as smart as you!  thanks again ;)

Comment: no problem, dont forget to accept answers if you found the correct solution. trust me im not smart :) have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are stuck with caching problem, Chrome loads the cache so that is why you are not able to update Try this,

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style/login.css?id=1">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Yes it's Chrome problem, I tried it  in Firefox now, and it works. But your solution didn't help for Chrome, now it's not finding the css file.

Comment: yes that's the alternative you did but what if you need to run it on chrome only, so by passing an id in href of link, Cache will get refreshed with the new css href